# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and it's returning a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" error in the console and I can't figure out why? The code is actually doing what I'd like it to do, but I'd like for it to not return any errors. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
var sig = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var sigTop = $('.svgWrap').offset().top - 500;
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (sigTop < winTop && !sig) {
        sig = true;
        animateSignature();
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have an item with the class `svgWrap`?  You can check in the debugger when you get to that line whether you have any hits or not.

Comment: See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.svgWrap` might not exist when the first `scroll` event fires; include the script at the end of the page, wrap it in a `$(document).ready`, or check for `.svgWrap`s.

```
var sig = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var svgWrap = $('.svgWrap');

    if (!svgWrap.length) {
        return;
    }

    var sigTop = svgWrap.offset().top - 500;
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (sigTop < winTop && !sig) {
        sig = true;
        animateSignature();
    }
});
```